# Unable to connect to USB devices in uwp

Tags: uwp, usb

I tried to connect USB devices in uwp according to the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/talking-to-usb-devices-start-to-finish) in MSDN, and also tried to download the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess) provided by MSDN to connect devices, but I still couldn't connect to usb devices.

What is the possible cause of this problem? Any directions or suggestions?

Here is part of my code:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="usb">
      <Device Id="vidpid:1532 0a14">
        <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific"/>
        <!--The following statement also tries-->
        <!--<Function Type="classId:ff * *"/>-->
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

C# code:

```
string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(0x1532, 0x0A14);
var finder =  DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs).GetResults();
//finder.Count always equals 0
```

About the registry for this device:

**Image 1**
[image: image 1]

**Image 2**
[image: image 2]

Comment: You are using the AQS returned from UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid,pid), it means the filter will look for a WinUSB USB device with the VID and PID, so is your device a WinUSB device? You can check it whether it’s a WinUSB device by looking at the service property (==WINUSB) for the device in DeviceManager.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This is actually an Xbox gamepad, and I can see the device on the device manager. The device path is: \ \? Usb#vid 1532&pid 0a14#0000c96c27402af7#{guid}. but what makes me confused is that the driver is dc1-controller.sys, and the inf is dc1-controller.inf.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT And I can get the device ID using `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(string.Empty)`, but using `UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(item.Id)` always returns null, I don't know why.

Comment: Based on the first step of this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/talking-to-usb-devices-start-to-finish#walkthroughwriting-uwp-app-for-usb-devices), have you installed the WinUSB.sys driver? In order to use the Windows.Devices.Usb namespace, the USB device must have the Winusb.sys driver loaded as its function driver.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT You're right. This is the key to the problem. Because the Xbox controller's filter driver is xboxgip.sys, not WinUsb.sys, so I'm looking for APIs for C# to communicate through xboxgip.Although Windows.Gaming.Input.Custom Namespace namespace looks like what I'm looking for, I found it didn't work after trying